# Execute attribute before class constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem validating the user of the page in ASP.Net my plan is using Attribute per page but it seams the constructor of the class is called first before the attribute. Is there a way to do this using Attribute?

i tried something like this

```
public class BaseAuthenticate : Attribute
{
    public BaseAuthenticate(string pageID)
    {
        // condition if current user is allowed in pageID, 
        // throws exception if not allowed
    }
}

[BaseAuthenticate("03902020-BC73-4DC0-A000-D4E20409FA2C")]
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // will not reach here if not validated in BaseAuthenticate
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Not an answer in any way, but the convention would be to name your custom attribute `BaseAuthenticateAttribute`.  the `Attribute` suffix will be inferred by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor such that it calls the superconstructor -

```
 public BaseAuthenticate(string pageID) : base() {
       //blah blah blah
       // Egyptian braces >>>
 }
```

That should execute the base constructor. Obviously, whatever the superclass needs as an argument will have to be put in `base()`.

Comment: It won't work since it is not an inheritance from class. Thanks for the response btw

Comment: Err, what? Yes it is.
`public class BaseAuthenticate : Attribute`